# Cardinality of of set surjection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be finite sets. Prove there exists a surjection $f:A \to B$ iff $\#B ≤ \#A$

For this question, does the pigeonhole principle just prove it, or is there more needed?

Edit: Also Can i use this to prove every subset of a finite set is finite

Comment: More is needed, of course. Whether you have developed the required tools, so this is trivial, or if part of the question is to develop these tools, it is impossible to tell from what you have written.

Comment: There is an exception to the proposition proposed to be proved: It's not true if $B$ is empty and $A$ is not. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Closing this as off topic is absurd.  I've voted to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

For finite sets $A$ and $B\ne\varnothing$, there is an *injection* $g:B\to A$ if and only if there is a *surjection* $f:A\to B$.

I think what you need here is only one direction: If there is an injection $g:B\to A$ then there is a surjection $f:A\to B$.  To prove that, let
$$
f(a)=\begin{cases} g^{-1}(a) & \text{if }a\in\{g(b):b\in B\}, \\[8pt] b_0 & \text{otherwise}, \end{cases}
$$
where $b_0$ is one element of $B$.